# How do I make truffle migrate replace just one contract?

Tags: truffle, migration

I have a dapp consisting of two contracts, which don't particularly have a dependency on each other or know about each other.

I want to replace one of the contracts, but not the other one. If I did `truffle migrate --reset` it would redeploy the one I want to keep, not to mention redeploying the "Migration" contract that it uses to keep track of what it's migrated. I thought the obvious thing to do was to make a new migration deploying the contract I'm changing and running `truffle migrate` without the `--reset`, and that seemed to work, but redeploying a contract over the previous one with the same name messed up the `.json` build file and caused my dapp to break expect extra function arguments that weren't there.

I think I can work through it by redeploying with a migration on mainnet, then doing a clean redeploy of the whole thing on testnet then editing the resulting build files by hand so that they know where to find the mainnet contracts, but this seems hackish and error-prone. Is there a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truffle has an `overwrite` flag you can use to select whether an already-deployed contract should be replaced when running `migrate --reset`

You can use it by including the following in your migration files:

```
// Don't deploy this contract if it has already been deployed
deployer.deploy(A, {overwrite: false});
```

In your case you could mark `migrations` and your first contract as `false`, then only your third contract will be replaced.

[See here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/migrations) for more info

Comment: OK, that seems to work, but I had to delete the `.json` file of the contract I was upgrading (not the whole build/ directory) before running the upgrade to avoid it getting subtly borked.

Comment: Interesting - I thought truffle would recompile automatically and replace the .json file before running the migrations to make sure this wasn't an issue

Comment: It seems to be somehow munging the old version and the new version together, producing function input parameter entries that aren't in either.

Comment: It worthy to note that `{overwrite: false}` has to be the last argument to `deploy` if the constructor of the contract needs any arguments.